# Can I Only Load a Plug-in on Front-end of Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm in a spot where my Constant Contact plug-in is triggering a problem on the Wordpress back-end and causing issues with the WYSIWYG editor. I've had this type of issue countless times before, and I'm just wondering if there's a way to ONLY load particular plug-ins on the FRONT of the site.

It seems really lame to not be able to use plug-ins because of these kinds of conflicts, and if it isn't possible, feel free to throw me some thoughts, ideas, hate mail, used band aids, or alternative solutions, thanks!

P.S. Totally open to hacking the plug-in files on this particular site if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is causing the issue, is it the styling or the Javascript?

Most plugins are setup to only load styles/scripts on the frontend. It sounds like this plugin was not setup properly and may require you to "hack" it up a bit.

Here is the codex page on how to load scripts/styles on the front-end only:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts